# Can an intersection of two context-free languages be an undecidable language?

Tags: computability, context-free, undecidability

I'm trying to prove that

$\exists L_1, L_2 : L_1$ and $L_2$ are context-free languages $\land\;L_1 \cap L_2 = L_3$ is an undecidable language.

---

I know that context-free languages are not closed under intersection.

This means that I can produce an $L_3$, which is undecidable.

An example would be $L_1 = \{a^n | n \in \mathbb{N}\} \cap L_2 = \{0\} = \emptyset$.

- Is this a correct proof?
- If not, how can I prove this theorem?
- Is the empty language decidable?

Comment: What research have you done?  Do you know what "undecidable" means?  Do you know how to prove that a language is decidable or not?  You ask "how can I prove this theorem" - what have you tried?  How have you tried to prove it?  Do you know how to prove that something  is/isn't decidable?

Comment: @D.W. Some. Yes. Yes. See above. By using known properties. Yes (same question as 2). How do these questions help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Context-free languages are decidable, and decidable languages are
closed under intersection.

So, though the intersection of two CF languages may not be CF, it is decidable.

Remarks on your example:

- $\emptyset=\{\}\neq$ $\{0\}$
- $L_1\cap\emptyset=\emptyset$  which is context-free.
- You cannot prove your claim, because it is wrong
- the empty language is decidable: the answer is always "no, this string is not in the empty set".

Comment: Is the intersection of two context-free languages then at least context-sensitive, or can it be just a decidable, but not context-sensitive language?

Comment: @polym Context-free languages are context-sensitive, and context-sensitive languages are closed under intersection. So, yes, the intersection of two CF languages is context-sensitive.

Comment: Ah right thanks. My mistake was not considering $CFL \subseteq CSL$ and the properties of CSL.

Comment: **Q1.** Is this problem decidable: "Is the intersection of two context free languages also context free?" **Q2.** Does all questions asking if operation on two languages of same type, not closed under that operation, result in the language of the same type are undecidable?

Comment: @Mahesha999 Comments can be used for clarification, not for new questions. So you should ask this in a new question. But you should make precise what you mean by the type of a language, and by an operation on two languages of the same type, if you want **Q2** to make sense.

Comment: By type I mean regular, CFL, dcfl, CSL etc.

Comment: @Mahesha999  As I said, "new question".  BTW, "etc"is unliukely to be part of a precise definition. If you say: "By type I mean regular, CFL, dcfl or CSL", that is precise. If you add "etc", it no longer is. Then a type can be any set of word sets, i.e. any element of $2^{2^A}$, where $A$ is the alphabet. Similar remark goes for operations on languages. I am not trying to give you a hard time, but the technical world is not very forgiving, and loosely stated questions are just a way to leave all the work to the answerer, which is unfair.

Comment: I felt "regular, CFL, dcfl or CSL etc." is enough to make sense that by "same type" I mean "same family of language in Chomsky's hierarchy". More verbose: $L_1 * L_2=L_3$ where $L_1$ & $L_2$ belong to same language family in Chomsky's hierarchy (say $family1$) and it is not closed under arbitrary operation $*$. Then is the problem "$L_3$ also belongs to the $family1$?" undecidable?

Comment: @Mahesha999 You included DCFL, which is not in the Chowsky hierarchy, and "etc"
which can be anything. So does that also include indexed grammars,
tree adjoining grammars, linear CF rewriting systems, ... ? I did not
suggest verbosity, but precision. The same applies to language
operations you may want to consider: what is their precise list, or
their characterization? You will get nowhere if you are not precise.
Furthermore comments are not intended for long discussion (this is my
last reply). You should try to build a proper question, which is a
good exercise by itself.

Comment: ohh very sorry. **[Wikipedia lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_grammar#External_links)** DCFL in Type-2 of Chomsky hierarchy, whereas indexed and tree adjoining grammar are listed in Type-1. Wikipedia must be wrong and you must be very very correct. And may be I was wrong too in thinking "arbitrary" operation **[means "any random"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/arbitrary)** operation(or not belonging to specific precise list).

Comment: @Mahesha999 Wikipedia is right. You are mis-reading it. DCFL are type 2 languages. But the Chomsky hierarchy consists only of four types, from 0 to 3, and DCFL is not one of them, it is a subset of some of them. Languages in DCFL are type 2 languages, but DCFL is not a type in that hierarchy.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that you understand what *decidable* means for a language $L$: it means that there is an algorithm that, given $x$, terminates and outputs either $x \in L$ or $x \notin L$ (correctly). It is easy to construct such an algorithm for the language $L = \emptyset$: it always returns $x \notin L$.

As [babou mentions in their answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/28532/20242), while context-free languages are not closed under intersection, it is easy to decide whether $x \in L_1 \cap L_2$ for any context-free $L_1,L_2$:

- First determine whether $x \in L_1$ and $x \in L_2$
- If both are true:

  - return $x \in L_1 \cap L_2$
- Otherwise:

  - return the converse.

As babou mentions, we only really use the fact that $L_1,L_2$ are themselves decidable.

Comment: So the empty language $L_{\emptyset}$ is decidable, because I can always say that $x \not\in L_{\emptyset}$ and my machine stops after telling me that?

Comment: @polym Exactly.